# /bin/sh: read arguments from pipe separately

Tags: shell, sh, command-line-arguments

I am using `dash` shell as `/bin/sh`.

The following command prints:

```
echo aa bb cc | while read X ; do echo $X ; done
aa bb cc
```

how can I read the arguments separately, ie so that it prints:

```
echo aa bb cc | while read X ; do echo $X ; done
aa
bb
cc
```

Comment: `printf "%s\n" aa bb cc | ...` (e.g. don't use `echo ...`) Also, avoid using CAPTIAL variable names -- those are generally reserved for sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `read` reads a line of input into the specified variable, the key is to make each input appear on a separate line. If you have control over `echo`, just replace it with `printf "%s\n" aa bb cc | ...`, e.g.

```
printf "%s\n" aa bb cc | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

(**note:** avoid using all CAPS for variable names -- those are generally reserved to the shell)

If you can't change `echo`, then add `sed` or `tr` to the pipeline, e.g.

```
echo aa bb cc | sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\n/g' | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

or with `tr`:

```
echo aa bb cc | tr ' ' '\n' | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

**Example Use/Output**

In all cases your output will be, e.g.

```
$ echo aa bb cc | tr ' ' '\n' | while read X ; do echo $X ; done
aa
bb
cc
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.